# Google Mirror API Playground not working anymore

Tags: google-mirror-api

starting yesterday the Playground stop working.
I can try to authorize with no results and i cannot see the cards posted for my user.
Anyone has the same problem?

I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems using it around when you posted your question, but it seems to be working correctly now. Try again. (And if you continue to have problems, you may want to [open a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).)